# Getting the tag of the item pressed in a ListView context menu?

Tags: java, android, listview, contextmenu

I have a list view populated with different views, each with a tag associated with them.  When one of them is long pressed, a context menu appears. I need to get a reference to the view pressed, and fetch the tag associated with it. Here is the code I have tried

```
    @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
    try {
        info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        return;
    }
    long id = getListAdapter().getItemId(info.position);
    ListView lv = (ListView) v;
    View row = (View) lv.getItemAtPosition((int) id);
    row_id = (Long) row.getTag(); // global variable 

}
```

row_id is the global variable that I want to set to the tag of the view pressed.  The tag is set correctly.  I get a NULLPOINTER when trying to fetch the id this way

Comment: Have you tried `menuInfo.targetView`? This should be the `View row` you want to get to, i.e. `row_id = menuInfo.targetView.getTag();`

Comment: @PhilippReichart you should make this content an answer